# Python-How to stop code checking every line of a text file individually?

Tags: python, file

so I'm working on a code that basically has a text file which stores a list of 'Products', and a user should be able to input what product `GTIN-8` code they want and get a receipt from it.
I've made it so that when the user inputs the `GTIN-8` code, the code looks through the Products text file to find a matching `GTIN-8` code. When it does, it should get that line of code and then write it to another text file called 'Receipt' (I couldn't think of any other way to do this). It should also say 'Product found' or 'That Product doesn't exist' depending if there is a match. However, my code checks every individual line of code and says on screen for every line of code if there's a match or not. I need to have an individual line of code so I can take the information of that line, but I don't want the code to check EVERY single line. Just like an overview of the entire file and pick out that specific line. I hope that makes sense.

```
with open("Productsfile.txt") as f:
    Found = False
    for line in f:
        if ProductsWanted in line:
            Receipt=open("ReceiptFile.txt","a")
            Receipt.write("%r x%r\n" % (line, AmountOfProducts))
            Receipt.close()
            print("Product found!")
            Found = True
    if not Found:
        print("That product does not exist")
```

(I deleted the screenshot/link and put it in as text, I am sorry if putting in a screenshot/link was the wrong thing to do)
Thank you!!!

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code.

Comment: @JoshLee sorry, I didn't know and I couldn't think of any other way to show it

Comment: Please, post the code as a text, here`s the [Markdown Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 0):

How many products are there?

If there are fewer than, say, a million, consider reading the contents of the file into a dictionary, keyed on the GTIN-8 code.

(Does that make sense?)

Comment: This should fit better in a comment.

Comment: There are only 5 products, I didn't want too many to start with. Thank you, I'll have a go at the dictionary thing!

Comment: Cool. If you need suggestions for how to do that, please give a shout.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to work on smaller file then you can read the file lines into a list and then check if the line is in list. Like this:

```
Lines=[x.strip() for x in open("file.txt")] #readlines has \n at the end of lines so use strip to remove it
If product in lines:
    print "line no =",lines.index(product)+1 
else:
    print "Product not found"
```